# How can I make Linux/Win10/Linux triple-boot work?

Tags: linux, windows, hard-drive, boot, multi-boot

I have two physical drives: 500GB Samsung 860 M.2 and 1TB WD SSD
The entire Samsung is Ubuntu 22.04 (`/dev/sdb`)
The 1st half of the WD is Windows 10 (`/dev/sda2`)
The 2nd half of the WD is Debian 12 (`/dev/sda3`)
This is the order in which the OSes were installed.

When I boot the machine, I'm presented with four (4) choices:

- Ubuntu
- Advanced options for Ubuntu
- Windows Boot Manager (on /dev/sdb1)
- UEIF Firmware Settings

When I choose `Ubuntu`, that's what I get.
When I choose `Windows Boot Manager`, I get Windows 10.

I think I've successfully installed Debian 12 on the 2nd half of the WD drive but I can't boot into it. (I was unable to complete the "grub installation" part bc. it always failed.)

How can I boot into the 3rd OS, Debian 12?
How can I get all 3 on my boot menu?

Comment: *IHMO* it's always tricky to have shared `/boot` and/or shared grub for multiple Linux installations. I don't know what most people do out there, but *to me* the general approach is to avoid installing/managing grub from more than one distro, if you insist on having a shared one. (With that said, you might still bump into problems unless you write/manage grub menuentries manually.) UEFI booting actually made things easier, in the sense that technically you can have multiple grubs without a hassle. In reality you may only find it to be the case until you get to know how UEFI booting works tho

Answer (score -1):

I am a fool. Logging in to my Ubuntu instance (where apparently my grub installation originated) then running `sudo update-grub` solved my issue.
I found inspiration in [Adding Other Operating Systems to the GRUB Bootloader](https://www.baeldung.com/linux/grub-bootloader-add-new-os)